# particlesystem issue in newer versions

Tags: webgl, three.js, fbo, rendertarget

In my search for a way to render cloud like textures I understood that I need to use texture and so on to store data for the next frame. 
Researching this further got me to some examples that make use of FBO and webgl rendertarget for particles. Even if it sounded great it seems that any of the examples do work in a newer version of threejs (like 50, or 51). If I am to switch to three49 it would render how it should.

To illustrate this problem I made this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pdpQ/1/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000000;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #info {
                color: #ffffff;
                font-family: Monospace;
                font-size: 13px;
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: bold;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            a {

                color: #0040ff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-86951-7']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function()
            {
                var ga = document.createElement('script');
                ga.type = 'text/javascript';
                ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
            })();
        </script>

        <!--         <script src="helvetiker_bold.typeface.js"></script> -->

        <script id="texture_vertex_simulation_shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

            varying vec2 vUv;

            void main() {

            vUv = vec2(uv.x, 1.0 - uv.y);
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

            }

        </script>
        <script id="texture_fragment_simulation_shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

            // simulation
            varying vec2 vUv;

            uniform vec3 origin;
            uniform sampler2D tPositions;

            uniform float timer;

            float rand(vec2 co){
            return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
            }

            void main() {

            vec3 pos = texture2D( tPositions, vUv ).xyz;

            if ( rand( vUv + timer ) > 0.99 ) {

            pos = origin;

            vec3 random = vec3( rand( vUv + 1.0 ) - 1.0, rand( vUv + 2.0 ) - 1.0, rand( vUv + 3.0 ) - 1.0 );
            pos += normalize( random ) * rand( vUv + 1.0 );

            } else {

            float x = pos.x + timer;
            float y = pos.y;
            float z = pos.z;

            pos.x += sin( y * 3.3 ) * cos( z * 10.3 ) * 0.005;
            pos.y += sin( x * 3.5 ) * cos( z * 10.5 ) * 0.005;
            pos.z += sin( x * 3.7 ) * cos( y * 10.7 ) * 0.005;

            }

            // Write new position out
            gl_FragColor = vec4(pos, 1.0);

            }

        </script>

        <!-- zz85 - end simulations -->

        <script id="vs-particles" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

            uniform sampler2D map;

            uniform float width;
            uniform float height;

            uniform float pointSize;

            varying vec2 vUv;
            varying vec4 vPosition;
            varying vec4 vColor;

            void main() {

            vec2 uv = position.xy + vec2( 0.5 / width, 0.5 / height );
            vec3 color = texture2D( map, uv ).rgb * 200.0 - 100.0;

            gl_PointSize = pointSize;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( color, 1.0 );

            }

        </script>

        <script id="fs-particles" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

            uniform vec4 pointColor;

            void main() {

            gl_FragColor = pointColor;

            }

        </script>

        <script>

                        var container;

            var scene, camera, light, renderer;
            var geometry, cube, mesh, material;

            var data, texture, points;

            var controls;

            var fboParticles, rtTexturePos, rtTexturePos2, simulationShader;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            scene.add( camera );

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls2( camera );
            controls.radius = 400;
            controls.speed = 3;

            //

            var width = 1024, height = 1024;
            // var width = 64, height = 64;
            // var width = 128, height = 128;

            if ( ! renderer.context.getExtension( 'OES_texture_float' ) ) {

            alert( 'OES_texture_float is not :(' );

            }

            // Start Creation of DataTexture
            // Could it be simplified with THREE.FBOUtils.createTextureFromData(textureWidth, textureWidth, data); ?

            data = new Float32Array( width * height * 3 );

            texture = new THREE.DataTexture( data, width, height, THREE.RGBFormat, THREE.FloatType );
            texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
            texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
            texture.needsUpdate = true;

            // zz85 - fbo init

            rtTexturePos = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, {
            wrapS:THREE.RepeatWrapping,
            wrapT:THREE.RepeatWrapping,
            minFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
            magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
            format: THREE.RGBFormat,
            type:THREE.FloatType,
            stencilBuffer: false
            });

            rtTexturePos2 = rtTexturePos.clone();

            simulationShader = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

            uniforms: {
            tPositions: { type: "t", value: 0, texture: texture },
            origin: { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3() },
            timer: { type: "f", value: 0 }
            },

            vertexShader: document.getElementById('texture_vertex_simulation_shader').textContent,
            fragmentShader:  document.getElementById('texture_fragment_simulation_shader').textContent

            });

            fboParticles = new THREE.FBOUtils( width, renderer, simulationShader );
            fboParticles.renderToTexture(rtTexturePos, rtTexturePos2);

            fboParticles.in = rtTexturePos;
            fboParticles.out = rtTexturePos2;

            geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

            for ( var i = 0, l = width * height; i < l; i ++ ) {

            var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
            vertex.x = ( i % width ) / width ;
            vertex.y = Math.floor( i / width ) / height;
            geometry.vertices.push( vertex );

            }

            material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

            uniforms: {

            "map": { type: "t", value: 0, texture: rtTexturePos },
            "width": { type: "f", value: width },
            "height": { type: "f", value: height },

            "pointColor": { type: "v4", value: new THREE.Vector4( 0.25, 0.50, 1.0, 0.25 ) },
            "pointSize": { type: "f", value: 1 }

            },
            vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vs-particles' ).textContent,
            fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fs-particles' ).textContent,
            blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
            transparent: true,
            depthWrite: false,
            depthTest: false

            } );

            mesh = new THREE.ParticleSystem( geometry, material );
            scene.add( mesh );

            var gui = new dat.GUI();
            gui.add( material.uniforms.pointColor.value, 'x', 0.0, 1.0 ).name( 'red' );
            gui.add( material.uniforms.pointColor.value, 'y', 0.0, 1.0 ).name( 'green' );
            gui.add( material.uniforms.pointColor.value, 'z', 0.0, 1.0 ).name( 'blue' );
            gui.add( material.uniforms.pointColor.value, 'w', 0.0, 1.0 ).name( 'alpha' );
            gui.add( material.uniforms.pointSize, 'value', 0.0, 10.0 ).name( 'size' );
            gui.add( controls, 'enabled' ).name( 'auto move' );

            scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 500, 500, 500 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, wireframe: true, opacity: 0.15 } ) ) );

            }

            function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();

            }

            var timer = 0;

            function render() {

            timer += 0.01;

            simulationShader.uniforms.timer.value = timer;
            simulationShader.uniforms.origin.value.x = Math.sin( timer * 2.3 ) * 0.5 + 0.5;
            simulationShader.uniforms.origin.value.y = Math.cos( timer * 2.5 ) * 0.5 + 0.5;
            simulationShader.uniforms.origin.value.z = Math.sin( timer * 2.7 ) * 0.5 + 0.5;

            // swap
            var tmp = fboParticles.in;
            fboParticles.in = fboParticles.out;
            fboParticles.out = tmp;

            simulationShader.uniforms.tPositions.texture = fboParticles.in;
            fboParticles.simulate(fboParticles.out);
            material.uniforms.map.texture = fboParticles.out;

            controls.update();

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is the code mrdoob used for `magicdust` and you can see there how only one particle is render instead of all of them. Furthermore, almost, if not all, of the examples from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1183 are not functioning.

So my questions are:

1. Can anybody tell me what I can do about this problem?
2. (Even if it is not mentioned in the title) Can anyone give me a basic and simple, but relevant, example on how to use the last frame to compute the next frame? I suppose this is what I need in order for my cloud simulation.

**Edit 1:**

Investigating the problem, it seems al the particles are rendered on the same spot. And scale on the particlesystem object only moves it on one axis or another. (It is as if they are pushed together by the bounds of the geometry...)

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

**Edit 2:**

It seems they are rendered somehow, but from a version to another their dimension, and scale differ. I managed somehow to see them in three52, moving the camere very close to 0,0,0 and they where there, but now as cube as I was expecting, but a simple plane. In three51, what I need to use, there weren't there at all.

So, can anybody can tell me how to work with the particle system whatsoever?